# Picasa 3.9 install is broken, Places feature doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, google-picasa

I had Picasa 3.9 working well with Precise Pangolin 12.04 yesterday but now I tried to use the Maps feature. I've broken my Picasa install.

I have tried to uninstall and to remove all Picasa files, but after a reinstall I have the same problem.  Is there a fix for the places feature?

Do I have to have Google Earth installed to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ~/.google/picasa/ folder, by running this command in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
rm -rf ~/.google/picasa/
```

(Make sure you don't accidentally put a space between `~` and `/`, or `/` and `.`. If you do, you'll delete everything in your home folder!)

Comment: Having the same issue, this doesn't help. Some people seem to imply that installing ie6 is necessary (see http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-picasa-39-in-linux-and-fix.html for instance) but winetricks ie6 (and ie8, for that matter) is broken as of two days ago.